# Bash: How to check if the last three string characters equals '***'

Tags: string, bash, shell, scripting

I know how to do it for one character:

```
[ "${filename: -1}" == "*" ]
```

Is it possible to do it for more?

Comment: `[[ $filename = *'***' ]]` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Why have you stopped in the `-1` value?

The [manual pages of bash](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) give the answer:

```
${parameter:offset}
${parameter:offset:length}
```

> If **`offset`** evaluates to a number **less than zero**, the value is used as
>   an offset in characters from **the end of the value** of parameter. If
>   `length` evaluates to a number less than zero, it is interpreted as an
>   offset in characters from the end of the value of parameter rather
>   than a number of characters, and the expansion is the characters
>   between `offset` and that result. Note that a negative `offset` must be
>   separated from the colon by at least one space to avoid being confused
>   with the ‘:-’ expansion.

Therefore

```
[ "${filename: -3}" == "***" ]
```